# Http Get Response Updates HTML but giving undefined error in console

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular4-httpclient

When I am updating my *html* with the response Obj using **HttpClient** it updates the values but gives multiple errors.

**File Name - auth-service.ts.**

```
    import { any } from 'codelyzer/util/function';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthService {

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
      get() {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>('/capi/v2/users/me', {
          observe: 'body',
          responseType: 'json'
        });
      }
    };
```

**File Name - dashboard.component.ts**

```
    import { AuthService } from './../../services/api/auth-service';

    import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-dashboard',
        templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
    })

    @Injectable()
    export class DashBoardComponent implements OnInit {
        user;
        constructor(private authService: AuthService) {};

        ngOnInit() {
             this.authService.get()
            .subscribe(
              (response) => {
                  this.user = response;
              }
            );
        }
    }
```

**The Response Obj is**

```
{
    "firstName": "xyz",
    "lastName": "abc",
    "active": true
}
```

**File Name - dashboard.component.html**

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
<h1 class="bold m-t m-b-xs">Hey there!</h1>
<h3 class="m-b">How are you doing today?</h3>

{{ user.active }}

<div class="block clear m-a">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="row m-t p-t">
        <div class="col-xs-12"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Details about errors in console:

[image: are described here].

Comment: Active seems to be a property of user. Remove @Injectable() from your component, since it is a component and not  a injectable.

Comment: Not Solved With That Still getting error

Answer (score 5):

Your error is likely because Angular attempts to evaluate `user.active` before the `get` request completes.

You can update `{{ user.active }}` to include a `?` (known as the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)):

```html
{{ user?.active }}
```

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

You could instead use `ngIf` to avoid rendering your container until the data is retrieved. i.e.:

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center" *ngIf="user">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use map function to return response to component. Replace this code with you service get.

```
get() {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>('/capi/v2/users/me')
    .map((resp) => resp)
    .catch((error) => error);
}
```

Comment: Also after adding the map m getting this error in addition - core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.